# Characteristic cycle of irreducible holonomic modules

Tags: d-modules

Let $i:A\rightarrow X$ be an affine locally closed inclusion of smooth complex varieties. What can be said about the characteristic cycle of the minimal extension $i_{*!}\mathcal{O}_A$?

How would one try to compute this cycle?

Are there situations where it can be computed in some combinatorial fashion (toric varieties, flag varieties...)?